# How to enable an addtional font in Libreoffice on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux

My goal is to use the font "Courier 10 Pitch" in Libreoffice on Raspbian Stretch on the Raspberry Pi 3B. At the raspi terminal, there is currently the following input and output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ grep --recursive 'Courier 10 Pitch' /usr/share/fonts/
Binary file /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0582bt_.pfb matches
Binary file /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0419bt_.pfb matches
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0582bt_.afm:FullName Courier 10 Pitch Italic
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0582bt_.afm:FamilyName Courier 10 Pitch
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0583bt_.afm:FullName Courier 10 Pitch Bold
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0583bt_.afm:FamilyName Courier 10 Pitch
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0419bt_.afm:FullName Courier 10 Pitch
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0419bt_.afm:FamilyName Courier 10 Pitch
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0611bt_.afm:FullName Courier 10 Pitch Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0611bt_.afm:FamilyName Courier 10 Pitch
Binary file /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0611bt_.pfb matches
Binary file /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0583bt_.pfb matches
```

It seems to indicate that the desired font is loaded on the system. On the other hand, the desired font does not appear in the list of available fonts inside the Libreoffice application. What is the solution ?

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config`

Comment: I tried that and then I rebooted. But still there is no option for Courier 10 Pitch in the font selection list of Libreoffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following instructions from https://raspberrytips.com/install-fonts-raspberry-pi/, I was able to get the font working in Libreoffice. I had to download a `.zip` archive containing the font from http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Courier-10-Pitch-Regular. I extract to desktop the contents of the `.zip` file. Next I use the File Manager application to create the directory `~/.fonts/`. Lastly, the command: `cp *.otf ~/.fonts/`. Now the font is available for use in Libreoffice.

Answer (score -1):

***Question***

> LibreOffice font is loaded on the system?

***Answer***

> Try LibreOffice 5 - all fonts built in, no loading needed! :)

[image: libre office 5]