# How to get my font to work

Tags: pi-3b+

I just downloaded a font and it's a .ttf file but it isn't working, I was hoping someone could help me figure out what's wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Does this help? ( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98805/how-to-enable-an-addtional-font-in-libreoffice-on-the-raspberry-pi )

Comment: what does this mean? `it isn't working`

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is very vague. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: downloading something doesn't mean you've actually installed it at all